# C++ call a function that outputs info from a txt file

Tags: c++, string, function

So I am a beginner in C++ and just completely stuck on a problem. I have background using Java which I am trying to apply but I end up just confusing myself even more. My teacher really hasn't taught us enough on C++ so I've been researching and youtubing for hours on end for something that could help me.

The problem is this:
Write a C++ program that:

1. Uses input redirection to go through the file of sections and counts how many of the 2660 courses are GERs. Output the count to the screen. Note that the section number sometimes contains letters, so you should read it in as a string (same as the course number).
2. Calls a function for each section. The function should output the course subject and number if the course is a GER and has CSCE as the course subject.

I already did part one and it works correctly. The txt file Im using contains the CRN, subject, course number, and yes/no on whether it is a GER for 2660 different courses.

My problem is with number 2. I haven't learned how to call a string or even use a string in a function like this.

This is what I have so far. The first part i am probably completely off but my int main i know is correct
Any input or a push in the right direction is greatly appreciated! thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printCsce(int total, int CRN, std::string subject, std::string courseNum, 
std::string courseSection, std::string yesNo);

void  printCsce(int total, int CRN, std::string subject, std::string courseNum,   
std::string courseSection, std::string yesNo){
    total=2660;
    for (int i=0; i <total; i++){
    cin >> CRN;
    cin >> subject;
    cin >> courseNum;
    cin >> courseSection;
    cin >> yesNo;

    if (subject=="CSCE" && yesNo=="Yes"){
    std::cout << CRN << subject << endl;
}
}
}

int main()
{
    int total=2660;
    int CRN;
    string subject;
    string courseNum;
    string courseSection;
    string yesNo;
    int sum=0;

    cin >> total;
    for (int i=0; i<total; i++)
    {
cin >> CRN;
    cin >> subject;
    cin >> courseNum;
    cin >> courseSection;
    cin >> yesNo;

    if (yesNo=="Yes") {
     sum++;
    }
}
cout << "There are "<< sum << " courses that are GERS."<<  endl;
    cout << printCsce << endl;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing special about using strings as arguments to functions. Just call the function with the variables as arguments.

Comment: I'm not really a Java programmer, but I don't think there's much difference between C++ and Java in this respect.

Comment: As a general piece of programming advice, apply the principal of divide and conquer. You aren't sure how to use string? Accomplish that: http://ideone.com/062lVD, then expand your understanding: http://ideone.com/yuMgtV

Comment: add to the above, an example of by-value vs by-reference. http://ideone.com/R4IyRs

Comment: thank you! im not using classes or anything so it was a little hard for me to understand how to apply it to my program. I understand some of it though. I updated to my program and now all i am getting is my print line from my main and then a 1. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take references for your arguments. When you pass by-value, the compiler makes copies so the extraction (`cin >> x)` only affects a local copy of the object:

```
void printCsce(int& total, int& CRN, std::string& subject,
    std::string& courseNum, std::string& courseSection, std::string& yesNo);
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to figure out my issues!